# How to complete "налей мне" and "отдай мне обратно": "чаёк," "чайка," or "чайку"?

Tags: словоупотребление, падежи, родительный-падеж, genitive-partitive

Here is a question in a test:

> Как корректно закончить следующие предложения?
>
> 1. Налей мне ... .
>
> (а) чаёк
> (б) чайка
> (в) чайку
>
> 2. Отдай мне обратно ... .
>
> (а) чаёк
> (б) чайка
> (в) чайку

I am at a loss as to how to answer this and why. With Sentence 1, I see that the third variant is much more common than the first two, but this by itself doesn't necessarily mean that the first two variants are ungrammatical. With Sentence 2, I suspect that the use of the partitive case, (в), is wrong because the entire tea is implied by **отдай мне обратно**. I guess the genitive case, (б), can be excluded likewise.

So I guess I should choose 1в and 2а as the only correct variants,  but I am unsure.

Which variants should I choose?

Comment: #1 - every option _seems_ correct, #2 - only option (a) - "Отдай мне обратно чаёк" (unless we are talking about a seagull).

Comment: Given your previous example with the snakes, 2в is also a plausible answer here ("give me the seagull back")

Comment: If option (в) had stress sign it would be more obvious if it's `seagull` or `some tea`.

Comment: I would answer 2в because it is unlikely the diminutive to be used with such request. So it is about a seagull.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With "Налей мне..."  any of the three options can be used:

- ...  чаек. Pour me THE tea.
- ... чайку. Pour me SOME tea.
- ... чайка. Same as чайку, more preferred if you  are younger.

Partitive (чайку) and Genitive (чайка) have almost completely merged in modern Russian with the genitive taking over: in Купи сахару/сахара, меду/меда, порошку/порошка the ending -у sounds outdated (mid 20th century or earlier). The last words to retain the partitive ending -у are those ending in -к: чаек, коньяк, лучок, etc. Those can take either ending 50/50.

You are competely right: after "Отдай мне ..." only чаек is possible. Unless we are talking about seagulls :-)

(Thanks @Alexander!)

Comment: Is there some reason the partitive case cannot be used with отдать?

Comment: @Wilson, yes, отдай мне implies you want all of the tea back, not just part of it.

Answer (score 2):

I would add my two cents to Sergey Slepov's good answer saying that although all three are *possible* I would personally use only the partitive case here. It sounds much more correct and it's not about age, it's about a good correct russian. I think it suits everyone no matter what age they are.